# Spinner show months from database

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, spinner

I'm trying to make a spinner which will load options dynamically. I want the spinner to show different months, but what if I have many of the some kind?

Look at my example:

Everytime the user uses this he makes a new date, therefore there are many days in one month and I want only one to be shown in the spinner:

The dates look like this

```
2013-10-04
2013-10-04
2013-10-02
```

I want to create the months, from my sql database.

How do I make one option in my spinner with october?

I hope this doesn't sound to confusing.

Thanks for your help.

This is my Sql database.

```
public class KilometerSQL {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "date";
public static final String KEY_KILOMETER = "kilometer";
public static final String KEY_LOCATIONS = "locations";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Kilometerdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "kilometertable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_KILOMETER + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_LOCATIONS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"


                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    }

public KilometerSQL (Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public KilometerSQL open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String date, int kortekm, String locations) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROWID, date);
    cv.put(KEY_KILOMETER, kortekm);
    cv.put(KEY_LOCATIONS, locations);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns = new String []{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_KILOMETER, KEY_LOCATIONS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iKilometer = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KILOMETER);
    int iLocations = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATIONS);

    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iDate) + " " + c.getString(iKilometer) + " " + c.getString(iLocations) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}


}
```

Comment: I know this may sounds trivial by why don't you use the Android's built-in `DatePicker`? : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: hmm.. I don't think i can use it..
Because when the user has picked one month, he will be able to see all the kilometers he has been running, and i want it to show each time, he went out for a run.

Comment: Okay, now I think I see your point. Please show your database create statement to give me the idea of how do you store these dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing your date as a `String` and this is wrong. If you'd store this into your DB as inits `int year, int month, int day` then you could pick rows which you're interested in. For example you could retrieve every row which `month=may` and so on. I know you have probably expected some example code but your question isn't very specyfic so that's why I haven't provide any.

Comment: Great. Good to know.. ;) Does that mean i should create 3 different KEYS, with Year, Month and days, instead of the one i called     'KEY_ID'?

Comment: Yes and also I would add the `_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT` which you may need in the future for things like `ListView`.

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna do that. I have one question then, right now i am using a edittext to save the date, should i use a datepicker instead? Or how do i store the day, month and year seperate?

Comment: You can do that in many ways, but I would use a datepicker because it's faster and easier to implement. You can also split the date from a EditText (into 3 parts) using regular expressions and then parse it to ints. Mind that users are not always very inteligent and thay may provide some incorrect data so some picker would be better here:).

Comment: Can you help me with the datepicker dialog in a chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38629/discussion-between-soulreaver-and-niller)

Comment: can you answer a question i have?